# InvalidArgumentException with composer

Tags: php, composer

I need your help, please.

At https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/installation.html#step-1-download-craft I have this instruction:

> "To create a new Craft project, run this command (substituting  with the path where Composer should create the project): composer create-project craftcms/craft "

I get

> "[InvalidArgumentException] .Could not find package craftcms/users/lestone2 with stability stable"

on entering `composer create-project craftcms/Users/lestone2`.

I get the same message on entering `php composer.phar create-project craftcms/Users/lestone2`

Can someone help me to set up the instruction correctly? Or do I have a permissions issue? (I am logged on as the admin.).

I found one related question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897084/could-not-open-input-file-composer but the issue there is not the same as mine.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I downloaded v1.7.3 of composer at https://getcomposer.org/download/ , and the file's integrity was confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

You're just entering the command slightly wrong is all. Where you go:

```
composer create-project craftcms/Users/lestone2
```

It should be:

```
composer create-project craftcms/craft /path/to/project
```

The craftcms/craft bit isn't a directory, it's vendor/package. The path to where you want your project to be (including the name) comes after. Good luck!

Comment: No worries Theodore. If you could mark this as the accepted answer that'd be appreciated :)